# passing multiple arguments to cucumber step definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Below code passes an argument to a cucumber step definitions:

```
Then /^I should see a message "([^\"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  page.should have_content (arg1)
end
```

Anyone could help me, how to pass multiple arguments?

Answer (score 5):

In order to pass multiple arguments, you need to have multiple "capture groups". Here's an example that has two capture groups:

```
Then /^I should see a message "([^\"]*)" and another message "([^\"]*)" $/ do |arg1, arg2|
  page.should have_content(arg1)
  page.should have_content(arg2)
end
```